# AuthenticatorService running but nothing in Account Settings

Tags: android, authentication, accountmanager, android-authenticator

It makes ten hours in a row that I try to create a Custom Account Type on my app.

My references are here :
http://docs.huihoo.com/android/4.2/training/id-auth/custom_auth.html

And the Android Developpers example [here](https://gitorious.org/0xdroid/development/source/00bf0f0296b6691a9ed93fa46eccf316f7b0222e:samples/SampleSyncAdapter/src/com/example/android/samplesync/authenticator/AuthenticatorActivity.java#L80-223).

My steps are :

1. Create an `Authenticator` class which extends `AbstractAccountAuthenticator` and overrides 7 methods.
2. Create `AuthenticatorService` class which extends `Service` class where I initialize `Authenticator` class
3. Create `AuthenticatorActivity` which extends `AccountAuthenticatorActivity` and where I create the user interface to enter credentials.
4. Add the service, permission and activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`
5. Create the `@xml/authenticator` file and set informations

With all of that well made, the only thing to do is to find a way to start the service.
So I created an other activity and start it in `onCreate()` method.

Time to test the app, I decided to run it on emulator (API16). The `MainActivity` is launched and we can see in Running Processes the app process, and the app service too !

So I go to DevTools/AccountsTester to insert credentials... But nothing here. Just Corporate and Email apps by default. I thought it was because of the emulator, so tried on my GS3 to add an account but it was the same.

In my logcat there's no error, and we can see the service is running(using `Log` class in my service class).

My code is exactly the same as my 2nd reference, I just change the server requests by returning a simple `true` instead, so in my case the service doesn't use external server to get response about submitted credentials.

Is there any step which I missed in my work ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the little mistake. When you use Android Studio and you make a new XML ressource file (in the example, the authenticator.xml file), some code is auto-generated :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ressources>

</ressources>
```

My mistake was to insert my `account-authenticatior` item in `ressources`, instead of let it as root.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<account-authenticator xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:accountType="e@string/account_type"
    android:icon="@drawable/myIcon"
    android:smallIcon="@drawable/myIcon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    />
```

I let this answer for people who could miss that like me. I also delete the `startService()` method in my `MainActivity`, because the `AuthenticatorService` is auto-launched.